# Difference between +e vs , e in throw Exception

Tags: java, exception

In Java, what is the difference between following 2 statements:

```
throw new Exception ("msg" + e);
```

and

```
throw new Exception ("msg", e);
```

I know both of them are possible. Is there any difference in how they work behind the scenes and which is a better practice to use?

Comment: [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`throw new Exception ("msg" + e);` throws a new `Exception` with a message that's a concatenation of `"msg"` and `e.toString()`, losing `e` stacktrace in the process.

`throw new Exception ("msg", e);` throws a new `Exception` with a message `"msg"` and `e` as the cause.

Answer (score 4):

The first one creates a new exception with a message that is a string concatenation of `msg` and the string representation of `e`. For this the `toString` method of `e` will be used. This effectively gives the message of the original exception and concatenates it with the string `msg`.

The second one creates a new exception with only the message `msg` and adds the original exception as a cause. Hence, more information from the original exception is available, for example the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`throw new Exception ("msg" + e);` throws a new `Exception` with a message that's a concatenation of `"msg"` and `e.toString()`, losing `e` stacktrace in the process.

`throw new Exception ("msg", e);` throws a new `Exception` with a message `"msg"` and `e` as the cause.